# How to validate that the user selected in select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have select form:

```
<form method="post" name="posting_txt" onSubmit="return blank_post_check();" id="post_txt">
        <select  style="background: transparent; border-bottom:5px;" name="subname" class="required">                           
            <option value="" > Choose subject </option> 
            <option value="aaa" > AAA </option>     
            <option value="bbb" > BBB </option>
        </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="post" name="txt" class="btn" id="post_button" onClick="time_get()">
</form>
```

I want to put alert label if the user pressed "post", but didn't choose a subject

Edit- thanks to maihan's answer I could fix it:

```
   function time_get()
   {
        var selected = document.getElementById("select_post_id");
        var selectedVal = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value;
       if(selectedVal != ""){
          //do whatever
       }else{alert('select an option');}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the logic in `time_get()` function you have.

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName(select).value ==''){
      alert("Select an option")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler on the form to prevent submitting it if the select has no value, then show an alert or add/unhide a warning `<label>`.

```
$('form#post_txt').submit(function(event){
    var subname = $('select[name="subname"]').val()
    if(subname === null || subname === "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        //warn user
    }
});
```

I would also recommend adding `selected="selected"` as an attribute on your first select option, so that it will be selected from the start, instead of a blank select.

Answer (score 0):

Maihan's answer is great, but just to improve, I would make the value of 'Choose Subject', 'NULL' and then validate using the if statement

```
<form method="post" name="posting_txt" onSubmit="return blank_post_check();" id="post_txt">
    <select  style="background: transparent; border-bottom:5px;" name="subname" class="required">                           
        <option value=NULL > Choose subject </option> 
        <option value="aaa" > AAA </option>     
        <option value="bbb" > BBB </option>
    </select> 
<input type="submit" value="post" name="txt" class="btn" id="post_button" onClick="time_get()">
```

Then... js...

```
function time_get(){
   if(document.getElementByClassName(required) != NULL){
      //do whatever
   }else{alert('select an option')}
}
```